# Second legend box doesn't have correct symbols/markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I have four sets of data all plotted on the same figure. I want two separate legend boxes (one legend box for "set1" and "set2" and another legend box for "set3" and "set4").

The problem is that I can't get the second legend box to associate the correct symbols with the sets. It just uses the symbols for set1 and set2, instead of using the symbols for set3 and set4.

I've read so many different things on matplotlib.org and I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [1,2,3]
x2 = [4,5,6]
x3 = [7,8,9]
x4 = [10,11,12]

y1 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [4,5,6]
y3 = [7,8,9]
y4=[10,11,12]

set1 = plt.plot(x1, y1, '.', color="red")
set2 = plt.plot(x2, y2, '*', color="blue")
set3 = plt.plot(x3, y3, '^', color="green")
set4 = plt.plot(x4, y4, 'x', color="black")

label_set1_and_set2 = ["set1", "set2"]
label_set3_and_set4 = ["set3", "set4"]

leg1 = plt.legend([set1, set2], labels=label_set1_and_set2,  loc=0, title="Set1 and Set2", frameon=True, fontsize=10)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.add_artist(leg1)
leg2 = plt.legend([set3, set4], labels=label_set3_and_set4, loc=4, title="Set3 and Set4")

plt.show()
```

Set3 should be represented by the green triangle and set4 by the black "x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the mixing of argument types. You can use any of

```
plt.legend(handles, labels)
plt.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
```

but not

```
plt.legend(handles, labels=labels)
```

Secondly you need to unpack the list of lines to supply to the legend.

In total:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [1,2,3]
x2 = [4,5,6]
x3 = [7,8,9]
x4 = [10,11,12]

y1 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [4,5,6]
y3 = [7,8,9]
y4=[10,11,12]

set1, = plt.plot(x1, y1, '.', color="red")
set2, = plt.plot(x2, y2, '*', color="blue")
set3, = plt.plot(x3, y3, '^', color="green")
set4, = plt.plot(x4, y4, 'x', color="black")

label_set1_and_set2 = ["set1", "set2"]
label_set3_and_set4 = ["set3", "set4"]

leg1 = plt.legend(handles=[set1, set2], labels=label_set1_and_set2,  loc=0, 
                  title="Set1 and Set2", frameon=True, fontsize=10)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_artist(leg1)
leg2 = plt.legend(handles=[set3, set4], labels=label_set3_and_set4, loc=4, 
                  title="Set3 and Set4")

plt.show()
```

[image]